# std::bad_weak_ptr from shared_from_this()

Tags: c++, c++17, shared-ptr

I'm building an asynchronous program where the `boost::asio::io_context` has a shared pointer to my object.  When my object stops posting asynchronous work with callbacks to itself, my object should die.

I'm using [`std::enable_shared_from_this<T>::shared_from_this()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/enable_shared_from_this/shared_from_this) to give references of myself to the context.  However, when I call `shared_from_this()`, a [`std::bad_weak_ptr`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/bad_weak_ptr) is thrown.

[cppreference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/enable_shared_from_this/shared_from_this) says:

> It is permitted to call shared_from_this **only** on a previously shared object, i.e. on an object managed by `std::shared_ptr` (in particular, `shared_from_this` cannot be called during construction of `*this`). `std::bad_weak_ptr` is thrown (by the `shared_ptr` constructor from a default-constructed weak_this) (since C++17).

I am creating the object with `std::make_shared<...>()`, so I thought the "previously shared object" was satisfied.  How can I avoid this exception?

MCVE:

```
// :! g++ % -std=c++17 && ./a.out
#include <memory>

class Object : std::enable_shared_from_this<Object> {
public:
    std::shared_ptr<Object> get() { return shared_from_this(); }
};

int main()
{
    std::make_shared<Object>()->get();
}
```

I'm able to compile/run [sample code from Boost.Beast](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_70_0/libs/beast/example/http/server/async/http_server_async.cpp) that does exactly the same thing without any issue.  I'm not sure what the difference is between my code and the linked sample.  That sample looks like this:

```
// Accepts incoming connections and launches the sessions
class listener : public std::enable_shared_from_this<listener>
{
    net::io_context& ioc_;
    ...

    void run()
    {
        // The new connection gets its own strand
        acceptor_.async_accept(
            net::make_strand(ioc_),
            beast::bind_front_handler(
                &listener::on_accept,
                shared_from_this()));
    }
    ...
};

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    ...
    // The io_context is required for all I/O
    net::io_context ioc{threads};

    // Create and launch a listening port
    std::make_shared<listener>(ioc, ...)->run();
    ...
    ioc.run();
    ...
}
```

Comment: You need to inherit publicly from `enable_shared_from_this`. It looks like you forgot to provide an access specifier when you inherited.

Comment: I see some close votes.  I wouldn't call this a typo.  I had the problem in the office, then again when I implemented a smaller example at home. Then again when I reduced it down to the MCVE.  The simple comment really helped something that I had spent 4 hours on.  Glad the solution was so simple.

Answer (score 1):

For the sake of completion, sometimes you just need a second pair of eyes.

This behavior occurs in `gcc` (unconfirmed in other implementationis) when inheritance is private.

The corrected MCVE:

```
// :! g++ % -std=c++17 && ./a.out
#include <memory>

class Object : public std::enable_shared_from_this<Object> {
public:
    std::shared_ptr<Object> get() { return shared_from_this(); }
};

int main()
{
    std::make_shared<Object>()->get();
}
```

Comment: The problem should occur on on all implementations. `std::make_shared<T>` can't see the non`public` parts of `T` so `private` inheritance from `std::enable_shared_from_this` is indistinguishable from not inheriting from it at all. Consequently, it doesn't know that it is supposed to set the object's self `weak_ptr`.